# Unpacking a numpy array into columns of a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
array([(26, 8, 32), (2, 2, 1), (4, 5, 3), (3, 3, 2), (3, 1, 5), (4, 4, 3),
       (4, 2, 10), (31, 10, 58), (7, 7, 4)], dtype=object)
```

I want to unpack this into a `dataframe` such that

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
26      8     32
2       2      1
4       5      3
3      3       2
3      1       5
4      4       3
4      2       10
31    10       58
7     7        4
```

Infact this output is being generated by using an `apply` function on an existing `df` and returning 3 values.
So would be fantastic, if I can assign the 3 values into the columns of the `df` directly (versus storing in an array)...
Thanks!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['A','B','C'])` doesn't work for you?

Comment: pd.DataFrame(a) will this work ?

Comment: @QuangHoang the error I get is ValueError: Shape of passed values is (9, 1), indices imply (9, 3)

Comment: @BENY The format I get is  ````
0
0 (26, 8, 32)
1 (2, 2, 1)
2 (4, 5, 3)```` Essentially its not splitting the elements into columns.

Comment: @FlyingPickle it wokrs for me , what are you doing exactly? see my answer

Comment: You should also provide the context of the code (the previous dataframe and the apply command), maybe you can avoid this altogether

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([(26, 8, 32), (2, 2, 1), (4, 5, 3), (3, 3, 2), (3, 1, 5), (4, 4, 3),
              (4, 2, 10), (31, 10, 58), (7, 7, 4)], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A','B','C'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0  26   8  32
1   2   2   1
2   4   5   3
3   3   3   2
4   3   1   5
5   4   4   3
6   4   2  10
7  31  10  58
8   7   7   4
```

Comment: Thanks all. The array is created as an output of an ````apply````.  Strangely, when I copy the output over to a new variable, it works, but not if I convert it directly :(

Comment: @FlyingPickle Sounds like you need to make a [mre]